# What actually is going on when we do structure type casting?

Tags: c, struct, casting

Here ([how to cast from one type to another in c](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4013041/how-to-cast-from-one-type-to-another-in-c)) we have nearly the same question but without explanation how structure type casting works.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <ctype.h>

typedef struct {
  int Type;
  int Type2;
}foo;

typedef struct {
  char cData[40];
}bar;

int main()
{
  bar b1;
  strcpy(b1.cData,"11"); 
  (struct foo *) &b1;  // What is going on here? What have changed at this point?
  return 0;
}
```

We have different sizes - sizeof (foo) > sizeof (bar). So what is happened after casting?

Comment: Are you sure that this compiles? Pointer-to-pointer casts are allowed, but I don't think that struct-to-pointer works.

Comment: "What is going on here?" - assuming you *meant* to use `&b1` (otherwise, "what's happening after casting?" is "fixing the compile-time errors") then the answer is *nothing*. You never do anything with the result of the cast. It is, for all intents, a do-nothing line of code. And if you actually tried to do something with it, you'd be back to fixing compile-time errors, as there is no `struct foo` type that can be resolved.

Comment: Nikita, aside from the obvious pointed out above, casting allows memory to be taken as being from a `type` other than its current type. The bits in memory do not change, only the window you are looking at them through changes. Why does it matter? Primarily, a given `type` has a given **size** and by virtue of being that type, it allows the compiler to correctly handle pointer arithmetic for that type. (i.e. `char *p = "abc";` `*(p + 1)` refers to `b`, `p[2]` refers to `c`.) However, if cast to another `type`, say `short` ( **size 2-bytes**), `*((short)p + 1)` no longer points to `b` in memory.

Comment: regarding this line, which does not compile, '(struct foo *) b1;' all the does is tell the compiler to look at b1 as if it were a pointer to the struct foo.  however, a bare symbol name 'b1' on a line does not compile.  please edit your question by posting code that does cleanly compile (enable all the warnings on your compiler)

Comment: @WhozCraig I meant from compiler point of view. I understand that code is useless. Sorry for mistake, I have improved it.

Comment: @David thank you for so full and clear explanation, that's what i wanted to understand!

Answer (score 2):

You cannot cast one structure type into another. You can only cast a *pointer* to one structure type to point to another, in which case nothing actually happens to it--it's just a memory address, and it is re-interpreted as pointing to a different kind of thing.